# Combination with repetitions explanation?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

There are 4 basic combinatorial formulas which depend on whether or not you allow repetition and whether or not order matters.

For 3 of them I can explain exactly why the formula is the way it is from the top of my head. But I don't know why the formula for "repetition allowed, order does not matter" is what it is. In this case we have:

$$\binom{n+k-1}k$$

Why?

We have $n$ elements, we are picking $k$ there are $n^k$ different sets we can construct. Then there are $k!$ different permutations of that set, so in my head the formula should be:

$$\frac{n^k}{k!}$$

I am probably wrong, so how do we get the correct formulation?

Comment: If you are picking $k$ items from $n$ distinct elements with "repetition allowed, order does not matter" then *stars and bars* would suggest ${n+k-1 \choose n-1}={n+k-1 \choose k}$ since you have $k$ *stars* and $n-1$ *bars*

Comment: To see that $\frac{n^k}{k!}$ is wrong, (A) consider that it is often not an integer and may be less than $1$ (e.g. when $n=1,k=2$) and (B) does not work even with a small example such as $n=2,k=2$ where it suggests two possibilities when in fact there are  three: $XX,XY,YY$.